# how to remove all $_GET params except my owns

Tags: php, get

need to remove all `$_GET` params from address bar - set by facebook etc - except my own `id` and `title`

something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['any-key-except-id-or-title'])){
    header('location: my-native-url');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through `$_GET` and remove any elements with another key. Then use `http_build_query()` to create a query string based on the remainder.

```
foreach (array_keys($_GET)) as $key) {
    if ($key != 'id' && $key != 'title') {
        unset($_GET[$key]);
    }
}

header('Location: my-native-url?' . http_build_query($_GET));
```

Comment: Also: `$_GET = array_intersect_key($_GET, array_flip(['title', 'id']));` for the key filtering as a one-liner. (Could also fuse it with the `header()` but that's pushing readability.)

Comment: `$myParams = ['page','id','product'];
$getParams = $_GET;
$array = [];

array_map(function($k,$el) use ($myParams,&$array) {
    if(in_array($k,$myParams)){
         $array[] = [$k => $el];
    }
},array_keys($getParams),$getParams);

$query = http_build_query($array[0]);
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],0,strpos( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],'/'))).'://';
header('Location: '.$protocol.$host.'?'.$query);`